# Can "solitons" be explained by linear wave equation?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, waves, solitons

In this Wikipedia page about [the history of solitons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soliton#History), the author say that the observations made by Scott Russell "could not be explained by the existing water wave theories" at that time.

However, if we work with the most naive linear wave equation, $\partial_t^2 u = \partial_x^2 u,$ we find that solutions are not dispersive - in fact, it is well known that $f(x\pm ct)$ are solutions. This is a wave which looks like a "soliton" because they do not merge and maintain their own shape perfectly. Of course, this is not a real soliton, but it at least shows that a stable wave packet is possible in simple models.

**So why is the observation "not explained" with these old theories? I just need a more detailed explanation.** For this to make sense, there need to be a model (i.e. a PDE) some time age that does not show soliton behavior, but is more sophisicated than the simple linear wave equation, I presume.

Comment: The description of water waves current at the time were the approximate [Airy theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airy_wave_theory) and the more accurate [Stokes theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stokes_wave), both of which were experimentally supported, but neither of which exhibit solitonic behaviour. Water waves are dispersive and cannot be described by the linear wave equation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/78158/